How is it called the border around the previously-selected element in a list?
On several interfaces showing collections of selectable elements, there is a special display for "last previously selected element", as illustrated in these screenshots:




I also noticed it on Thunderbird, where in my current theme, it shows a distinction between "Selected" (dark blue), "previousy selected" (gray), "hovered" (light gray) and "normal" (white):



I want to see if it can be implemented in CSS, but I don't know how it's called. Is there some specific terminology for this kind of state/behavior? I guess it's related to a cursor (since in some cases, using the keyboard arrows will use it as starting point), but I'm not sure.

Interesting question! I don't know the term either, sadly. What I can tell you is that I would be surprised if you implement this in pure CSS, as CSS doesn't really access state history as far as I know. Button states in CSS are limited to :hover, :focus, and :active as far as I know. You should however be able to implement this in a few lines of JavaScript, toggling CSS classes :)

This feature is available in desktop applications because they have different windows that can be focused on. I don't know if there is a specific name for it, but I would call it an inactive (window) focus state. Web content does not have this functionality. Using JavaScript this might be possible, but its functionality in a web context is questionable anyway.
Be aware that it can also easily break accessibility features. An element that does not have focus, but is marked as previously selected, or rather previously focused, should not be styled in any way that even remotely suggests that it has focus. Otherwise it will confuse users.
That border you asked about is called an outline. CSS has the outline property and it is by default used for the focus and active state of interactive elements. If you want a "previously focused" element to have an outline too, make sure people understand the difference. I have my doubt it's a good idea though.

In my case, it's for a React application, so in a desktop context. And the outline is needed so that, when I switch components, I keep the context in view. I just added an example screenshot from Thunderbird, in which a single window with several components needs this "outlined" state to allow users to know, for instance, which folder is currently being browsed.

If it's a feature users are going to appreciate then go for it. Just keep accessibility in mind so it won't harm anyone's routine.

"Inactive window focus" is what I would say!
